# 0 results when using COUNT with HAVING but rows exists actually - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where I want to count records per domain

I have query like this. [Here is sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70daac/3) of  table schema and query

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*),
    SUBSTRING_INDEX( TRIM( LEADING 'www.' FROM TRIM( LEADING 'http://' FROM TRIM( LEADING 'https://' FROM link ) ) ), '/', 1 ) AS domain 
FROM
    links 
WHERE
    source = 'web' 
    AND DATE( last_seen ) = DATE( NOW( ) ) 
HAVING
    domain = 'testingwebsite.com'
```

It returns 0 results when using `SELECT COUNT(*)` but it returns more than result when using `SELECT *`

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You missed  group by domain

```
    SELECT
        COUNT(*),
        SUBSTRING_INDEX( TRIM( LEADING 'www.' FROM TRIM( LEADING 'http://' FROM TRIM( LEADING 'https://' FROM link ) ) ), '/', 1 ) AS domain 
    FROM
        links 
    WHERE
        source = 'web' 
        AND DATE( last_seen ) = DATE( NOW( ) ) 
     group  by  domain  
    HAVING
        domain = 'testingwebsite.com'
```

if you don't add  the column name for group by you obtain  an unpredctable value for count(*)  (the first enccounterd  by db engine .. in your case 0)

this happen for mysql version < 5.7  (starting form mysql 5.7 the use of an aggregation function without group by is not allowed  also for avoid this situation=

Comment: Actually... this happens if the only_full_group_by setting is disabled. In MySQL 5.7+ this setting is enabled _by default_, in earlier versions it was disabled by default.

Comment: It is `domain` which is unpredictable. If the DBMS happens to pick 'testingwebsite.com', then it shows the complete count (regardless of the domain); if it happens to pick another domain, it doesn't return any row.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to add the `GROUP BY`.  First, you should understand why.

You have an aggregation query with no `GROUP BY`.  This is *always* going to produce one row.  However, the unaggregated column (`domain`) will have an *arbitrary* value.  It might or might not match the domain in your comparison.

You can fix this in multiple ways.  The most efficient is to dispense with the `domain` in the `SELECT` and just reference it in the `WHERE`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM links l
WHERE source = 'web' AND
      last_seen >= CURDATE() AND -- probably no last_seen values in the future
      'testingwebsite.com' = SUBSTRING_INDEX( TRIM( LEADING 'www.' FROM TRIM( LEADING 'http://' FROM TRIM( LEADING 'https://' FROM link ) ) ), '/', 1 )
```

This is guaranteed to return one row, whether or not any rows match the `WHERE` clause.  If no rows match, then the count will be `0`. I suspect that is what you want.

Notice that I also changed the date comparison.  This allows the query to use an index on `links(source, last_seen)`.

Finally, if you actually do want the domain in the `SELECT` but don't want to repeat it, I recommend a subquery:

```
SELECT domain, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT l.*,
             SUBSTRING_INDEX( TRIM( LEADING 'www.' FROM TRIM( LEADING 'http://' FROM TRIM( LEADING 'https://' FROM link ) ) ), '/', 1 ) as domain
      FROM links l
     ) l
WHERE source = 'web' AND
      last_seen >= CURDATE() AND -- probably no last_seen values in the future
      domain = 'testingwebsite.com'
GROUP BY domain;
```

Note that this will return no rows if the domain does not exist in the data.

A comment on performance.  This version does materialize the subquery, which incurs overhead (and is a short-coming of MySQL but not other databases).  However, your version not only materializes the subquery but it also aggregates all the data, so this should still be faster than using `HAVING`.  In general, it is better to filter *before* aggregation rather than afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You must group by domain:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*),
    SUBSTRING_INDEX( TRIM( LEADING 'www.' FROM TRIM( LEADING 'http://' FROM TRIM( LEADING 'https://' FROM link ) ) ), '/', 1 ) AS domain 
FROM
    links 
WHERE
    source = 'web' 
    AND DATE( last_seen ) = DATE( NOW( ) ) 
GROUP BY domain
```

If you want results for a certain domain you can add:

```
HAVING
    domain = 'testingwebsite.com'
```

`HAVING` is only suitable with `GROUP BY` in a SQL statement:

> a HAVING clause must come after any GROUP BY clause and before any
>   ORDER BY clause

from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Comment: While it is true that OP's query is lacking `GROUP BY`, I doubt that `HAVING` is only valid with `GROUP BY` in general. It should be possible to write something like: `select * from client c where exists (select 1 from orders o where o.client_id = c.client_id having count(*) > 1)` to find all clients with more than one order.

Comment: This is why I say *suitable* and not *valid* and this is why I posted a quote from the documentation.

Comment: Ah, so I misinterpreted "suitable". Sorry.